# search all pages of long pdf for string

Tags: pdf, evince

I used a ghostscript command to unite all the pdf files in a directory into one which is about eighty pages long. When I run a search for a string with evince, it tells me the number of times it was found *just on that page*. If I keep clicking next it will take me to the term on later pages. Is there a setting in evince which one can change such that it will find *every* ocurence of a string in a pdf, without you needing to help it? If not, is there a better pdf viewer for linux or even command line tool which can do this (tell me at least on which page numbers the term is to be found)

Comment: Can this be done in LibreOffice Write rather than evince? https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/65572/how-do-i-find-number-of-specific-instances-of-a-specific-word-in-a-large-document/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options to search pdfs on the command line:

1. Using the tool [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org/), which does what it's name suggests. It is compatible with GNU grep but works for pdf files.

```
pdfgrep 'pattern' yourfile.pdf
```

2. Use `pdftotext` from `poppler-utils` (should be installed by default on Ubuntu Desktop), convert it to a plain text file and use standard grep:

```
pdftotext yourfile.pdf - | grep 'pattern'
```

Comment: That pdfgrep was truly fantastic for the purpose : if you give it `--page-number` it tells you what page number the term was found on, there is `--ignore-case` and there is `--page-count` which just returns the number found per page.